# gdal.Translate convert batch asc to geotiff

Tags: python, raster, tiff, gdal

I have a batch of asc files which i want to mosaic them together and get one tif as output.

I tried with gdal.BuildVRT to build a vrt file first and use gdal.Translate to convert the vrt file to geotiff.

```
  import os
  import gdal
  import glob
  from osgeo import osr
  path = 'C:\\Data\\asc files\\'
  os.chdir(path)
  gdal.BuildVRT('out.vrt',glob.glob(path+'\\*.asc'))
  gdal.Translate('out.tif','out.vrt',format='gtiff')
```

error occurred at gdal.Translate, 'ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.'

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've already figured this out by now, but for anybody viewing in the future, you misread the parameters. The function definition shows the 1st param is the destination, while the second param should be source data. Also, format is typically no longer required, as it is inferred from the destination file extension.

Comment: Thanks for the format remainder! The parameter order should be alright in my code.